# Removing time stamp while assigning(binding) a date to text block in silverlight

Tags: c#, binding

i am facing issue to Removing time stamp while `assigning(binding)` a date to text block in silverlight 
t have been trying to do like this

```
date.Text = date.ToString();
date.text is a text block  and xaml code is 
<TextBlock  x:Name="date" Text="" Style="{StaticResource Label}" />
```

in this case am getting output like `date:2/2/2001 12:00:00 AM` but i want output like  `date:2/2/2001`.

Comment: Are you assigning or binding? They're completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

you should try `date.Text = date.Date.ToString("d");`

Comment: if i do like this it is working fine date.Text = date.Remove(date.Length - 12, 12); but i dont know this is appropriate way or not

Comment: edit: fixed string format; let ME be more specific: if your `TextBlock` is named 'textBlock1' and your `DateTime` object is named 'date1', your line should be:  `textBlock1.Text = date1.Date.ToString("d");`